# regex to restrict special characters except few

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I was able to write a regex to validate the below criterias for an input box.

1. contain minimum of 14 characters
2. contain at least 1 capital letter (A-Z)
3. contain at least 1 simple letter (a-z)
4. contain at least 1 number (0-9)
5. contain at least 1 special symbol (+=!@#$%^&*)

Regex -> `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[+=!@#$%^&*])(?=\\S+$).{14,}$`

However, this regex allows other special characters which are not mentioned. I want to restrict all the special characters except these `+=!@#$%^&*`

could someone help me to modify the given regex with the above criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.` that allows any character you can use a character set to restrict the allowed characters to a specific set:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[+=!@#$%^&*])(?=\\S+$)[0-9A-Za-z+=!@#$%^&*]{14,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use sets instead of a regular expression:

```
import string
upperSet   = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
lowerSet   = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
numberSet  = set("0123456789")
specialSet = set("+=!@#$%^&*")
allSets    = [upperSet,lowerSet,numberSet,specialSet] 
validSet   = set().union(*allSets)

isValid = len(pw)>=14 and validSet.issuperset(pw) \
          and all(s.intersection(pw) for s in allSets)
```

You could also use the translate method to convert each group of character into four codes that you then check to be exactly present in the translated string:

```
validCheck = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters + "0123456789" + "+=!@#$%^&*",
                           "1"*26+"2"*26+"3"*10+"4"*10)

isValid = len(pw)>=14 and set('1234') == set(pw.translate(validCheck))))
```